# Middle section of LED lights don't work

Tags: led-strip

Middle section of LED lights don't work.  I have stapled the LED lights to the ceiling and a short section of the lights don't work. What is the likely cause of this problem?   The LED lights are copper wired and do not appear to be insulated

Comment: most likely reason is you broke it

Comment: Staples and copper wire is a bad combination.

Answer (score 4):

The technical term for this condition is *busted*, also sometimes *broken*, *kaput* or other variants.

You *stapled* something electric?  Seriously!?  Stop and actually think about it.  Staples are made of steel, which is conductive.  When it punches thru thin layers of copper or other conducting material of your LED strip, it will electrically connect.  Since the staple does this in two places, it can connect two conducting parts of the device that aren't intended to be connected.

Don't do that.

Comment: (+1) Gosh! I didn't think someone could answer in a meaningful way to such a question. My first reaction was a double face-palm!!! (*OMG! Staples!!!*) Now I wish I could see a photo of the thing! :-) I hope it wasn't mains-powered! I'm beginning to think we should create a wiki thread (with photos!) related to what *NOT* to do with "electrical things"!